# How to override one Object with the values of another (lodash)

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm looking for a function that override the values of one object with another's if it exists, but I have not found it in the `lodash` documentation

```
var primary = {
    name: 'egg'
    weight: '2oz',
    meal: 'breakfast'
}
var secondary = {
    name: 'egg',
    weight: '3oz'
    state: 'uncracked'
}

var result = _.override(primary, secondary);

console.log(result)
// => { name: 'egg' weight: '3oz', meal: 'breakfast, state: 'uncracked' }
```

**How can I achieve this in functional programming?**

Comment: You can achieve this using `Object.assign()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Comment: What do you mean by "functional programming"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Checkout Lodash's `_.assign` function - https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#assign.

`Note: This method mutates object and is loosely based on Object.assign.`

```js
var primary = {
    name: 'egg',
    weight: '2oz',
    meal: 'breakfast'
};

var secondary = {
    name: 'egg',
    weight: '3oz',
    state: 'uncracked'
};

var result = _.assign({}, primary, secondary);

console.log(result)
// => { name: 'egg' weight: '3oz', meal: 'breakfast, state: 'uncracked' }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.js"></script></script>
```